# Why am I getting a bad request error when uploading files using flask?

Tags: forms, file, flask, werkzeug

## How do get a file from a form and store it in a database

```
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

app.config['UPLOAD_FILE'] = r'C:/Users/ujesh/OneDrive/VS CODE/YE/feed'

@app.route("/upload", methods=["POST","GET"])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['item']
        if file.filename != '':
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(filename)
            return render_template('/discussion.html', item = filename)
        else:
            render_template('/admin')
    else:
            render_template('/admin')
```

```
<form action="/upload" method="POST">
    <input type = 'file' name = 'file' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <br>
    <br>
    <h6 class = 'font'> Add Caption</h6>
    <br>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name = 'caption' id = 'caption' >
        <div  class="form-text">If you wish to caption your post, please enter a message</div>
      </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">submit</button>

</form>
```

I have all the necessary flask imports and code. When I attach a file and submit it, I get a bad request error, and I get '"POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 400 , error when I submit the code. Please could I get some help with this?

I have tried and copied loads of different approaches to this problem however I am not finding a solution.